# Need help to upgrade IronPython 2.0.2 to 2.7.5, called from C#

Tags: c#, python

I need to upgrade code calling IronPython from C# and would like to upgrade to IronPython 2.7.5. The problem is that one of the APIs has changed, and I am not familiar enough with the original code to fix it. I have written a console program that exhibits the problem

My Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var pythonTest = new PythonTest();
        pythonTest.LoadScript();
        Console.WriteLine("Area = {0}", pythonTest.Evaluate());
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
public class PythonTest
{
    private readonly ScriptEngine _engine;
    private readonly ScriptScope _scope;
    private ScriptSource _source;
    private PythonFunction _currentFunction;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, PythonFunction> _functions = new Dictionary<string, PythonFunction>();
    private readonly double _scriptInput;

    public PythonTest()
    {
        _scriptInput = 5;
        _engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        _scope = _engine.CreateScope();
    }

    public void LoadScript()
    {
        const string filename = @"../../Scripts/testscript.py";
        _source = _engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(filename);
        _source.Execute(_scope);

        string firstFunction = "";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in _scope.GetItems())
        {
            var pairValue = pair.Value as PythonFunction;
            if (pairValue != null)
            {
                _functions.Add(pair.Key, pairValue);

                if (_functions.Count == 1)
                {
                    firstFunction = _functions.Keys.First();
                }
            }
        }
        _currentFunction = _functions[firstFunction];
    }

    public string Evaluate()
    {
        if (_currentFunction == null)
            return null;

        var parameters = new ArrayList {_scriptInput};

        LanguageContext cxt = Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Providers.HostingHelpers.GetLanguageContext(_engine);
        var context = new CodeContext(new Scope(), cxt);
        object result = _currentFunction.__call__(context, parameters.ToArray());
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

My test script:

```
from math import *
def AREA(h):
  return (h * h)
```

This all works with the old Python DLLs. With the new DLLs the instantiation of the CodeContext (in the Evaluate method) is incorrect. The new API uses a PythonDictionary:

```
        public CodeContext(PythonDictionary dict, ModuleContext moduleContext);
```

I don't know how to modify the code to fix this problem. Any help would  be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LanguageContext` is a `PythonContext` so it can be cast.  You can then use that along with a `PythonDictionary` to create a `ModuleContext`.  Then you can use that along with a `PythonDictionary` to create your `CodeContext`:

```
PythonContext cxt = (PythonContext)Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Providers.HostingHelpers.GetLanguageContext(_engine);
PythonDictionary dict = new PythonDictionary();
ModuleContext modctx = new ModuleContext(dict, cxt);
var context = new CodeContext(dict, modctx);
```

Comment: Looks good. In my fumbling with code I missed the cast to a PythonContext. I will test this when I get back to work tomorrow. ! wIll sleep good tonight!

Comment: I just finished testing and this solution works. Thank you.